# TensorFlow Keras multi-GPU training bad performance

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, deep-learning, multi-gpu

**tensorflow multi-GPU training with mirrored strategy (GPU VS CPU) BAD performance**
Asking everyone for help.

I am so confused why GPU is slower than CPU on any condition I try...
I want to use six GPU with the mirrored strategy to reduce the training time.
I follow the below steps:
https://keras.io/guides/distributed_training/

I got bad performance with the machine
GPU: 6*GeForce RTX 2080 TI (10GB)
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4110 CPU @ 2.10GHz

run on the Docker container:
(1) Tensorflow version 2.0.0
(2) Cuda 9.0
(3) Cudnn 7.6
(4) Nvidia-driver 410.78 - install on server

I want to ask some questions.
(1) I want to know whether TensorFlow 'MirroredStrategy' can speed up the training speed??

For example, follow the link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy

(2) How to speed up the training speed(double/triple) by MirroredStrategy.
I follow the link to implement https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRMGoPqsn20
My example code works on Colab or github gist,
but you need to download the training data and put on the google drive space.
PS: The Colab only supports single GPU.

Colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ldJvdk6wfu-fXBb2iBjKe0q1ZnExGG17?usp=sharing

github gist:
https://gist.github.com/harrypotter02/0cc6ffe3bf7c520207dc7be96b1e8b66

**Test1:**

**CPU**, batch=64, samples:575478

```
Epoch 2/500 575478/575478 [===] - **16s** 28us/step - loss: 0.0735 - val_loss:
```

**Test2:**

**GPU**, batch=64, samples:575478

```
Epoch 1/500
1498/1498 [===] - 60s 40ms/step - loss: 0.0907 - val_loss: 0.0619

Epoch 2/500
1498/1498 [===] - **32s** 21ms/step - loss: 0.0592 - val_loss: 0.0522

my_mini_batch = BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync(GPU)
384 = 64*6
```

**Why so slower than CPU?**

```
    #import tensorflow_datasets  as ds #for debug
    os.environ["TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH"] = "true"       
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0,1,2,3,4,5'  
    gpu_table = ['/gpu:0','/gpu:1','/gpu:2','/gpu:3','/gpu:4','/gpu:5']
   
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=gpu_table)

    TrainDataPath = './Train'
    TestDataPath = './Test'

    def Load_Data(InputPath):
     Data_Total = np.array([])
     Label_Total = np.array([])
     folder_content = glob.glob(InputPath+'/'+'*_Label*')
     print('folder content=',folder_content)
     for File in folder_content:
        Label = np.load((File))
        Label_Total = np.append(Label_Total, Label)
        Feature = np.load([F for F in glob.glob(InputPath + "/" + File.split('/')[-1].split('Label')[0] + '*') if 'Label' not in F][0])
        Data_Total = np.append(Data_Total, Feature)

    Label_Total = Label_Total.reshape(-1, 1)
    Data_Total = Data_Total.reshape(-1, 1,3, 29)
    return Data_Total, Label_Total

    Train_Data, Train_Label = Load_Data(TrainDataPath)
    Test_Data, Test_Label = Load_Data(TestDataPath)

    def get_dataset():#for debug

     print('get_dataset()')
     print("Training_Data.shpae=", Training_Data.shape)
    
     global my_mini_batch
     my_mini_batch = 1
     BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA = 64 

     my_mini_batch = BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
     print('my_mini_batc=',my_mini_batch)
     print('BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA=',BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA)
     print('strategy.num_replicas_in_sync=',strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)

     Train_Dataset_1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Training_Data[:, :,:,0:5], Training_Data[:, :,:,5:15], Training_Data[:, :,:,15:25], Training_Data[:,:,:,25:])).batch(my_mini_batch).repeat()
     Train_Dataset_2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Training_Label).batch(my_mini_batch).repeat()

     global train_steps
     global valid_steps
     global test_steps
     train_steps = (int)( Training_Data.shape[0] / my_mini_batch)
     print('train_steps='+str(train_steps))

     valid_steps = (int)(Val_Data.shape[0] / my_mini_batch)
     print('valid_steps=' + str(valid_steps))

     test_steps = (int)(Test_Data.shape[0] / my_mini_batch)
     print('test_steps=' + str(test_steps))

     Valid_Dataset_1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Val_Data[:, :,: ,0:5], Val_Data[:, :,:,5:15], 
     Val_Data[:, :,:,15:25], Val_Data[:, :, :,25:])).batch(my_mini_batch).repeat()
     Valid_Dataset_2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Val_Label).batch(my_mini_batch).repeat()

     Test_Dataset_1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Test_Data[:, :,:,0:5], Test_Data[:, :,:,5:15], 
     Test_Data[:, :,:,15:25], Test_Data[:, :,:,25:])).batch(my_mini_batch).repeat()
     Test_Dataset_2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(Test_Label).batch(my_mini_batch).repeat()

     print('Replicas: ', strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
     print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))


     Train_Dataset_final = tf.data.Dataset.zip((Train_Dataset_1,Train_Dataset_2))
     Valid_Dataset_final = tf.data.Dataset.zip((Valid_Dataset_1,Valid_Dataset_2))
     Test_Dataset_final = tf.data.Dataset.zip((Test_Dataset_1,Test_Dataset_2))

     return Train_Dataset_final, Valid_Dataset_final, Test_Dataset_final

    with strategy.scope():
     PalmTh = 0.5
     A_layer1_Filters= 2
     B_layer1_Filters = 2
     C_layer1_Filters = 2
     D_layer1_Filters = 2

     L = 0.005
     F = 12
     Epochs = 500
     EarlyStopPatience = 10
     ChangeLrPatience = 8
     ChangeLrFactor = 0.9

     Test_Para = []

     A_IN_Cell = Input(shape=(1, 3, 5), name = "Cell")
     PX = Input(shape=(1, 3, 10), name = "X")
     PY= Input(shape=(1, 3, 10), name = "Y")
     PZ = Input(shape=(1, 3, 4), name = "Z")


     L1= Convolution2D(filters = A_layer1_Filters, 
             kernel_size = 3, 
             strides = 1, 
             padding = 'valid', 
             data_format = 'channels_first', 
             use_bias = True ,
             name = 'Conv1_Height_Cell', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001)) 
     (A_IN_Cell)

     LH1 = Activation(custom_HardTanh)(L1)
     LH1_out= Flatten()(LH1)

     L2= Convolution2D(filters = B_layer1_Filters, 
             kernel_size = 3, 
             strides = 1, 
             padding = 'valid', 
             data_format = 'channels_first', 
             use_bias = True ,
             name = 'Conv1_ProjectionX', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001)) 
     (PX)

     LH2= Activation(custom_HardTanh)(L2)
     LH2_out= Flatten()(LH2)

     A_Convolution1 = Convolution2D(filters = C_layer1_Filters, 
             kernel_size = 3, 
             strides = 1, 
             padding = 'valid', 
             data_format = 'channels_first', 
             use_bias = True ,
             name = 'Conv1_ProjectionY', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001)) 
     (PY)

     A_Hidden1 = Activation(custom_HardTanh)(A_Convolution1)
     A_Out = Flatten()(A_Hidden1)

     Centroid_Convolution1 = Convolution2D(filters = D_layer1_Filters, 
             kernel_size = 3, 
             strides = 1, 
             padding = 'valid', 
             data_format = 'channels_first', 
             use_bias = True ,
             name = 'Conv1_Centroid', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001))(PZ)

     Centroid_Hidden1 = Activation(custom_HardTanh)(Centroid_Convolution1)
     Centroid_Out = Flatten()(Centroid_Hidden1)

     ConcatentaLayer = concatenate([LH1_out, 
               LH2_out, 
               A_Out,
               Centroid_Out]
               )

     DenseLayer1 = Dense(F, use_bias = True, activation=None, 
     activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.00001))(ConcatentaLayer)
     DenseLayer1 = Activation(custom_HardTanh)(DenseLayer1)
     Output = Dense(1, use_bias = True, activation='sigmoid')(DenseLayer1)

     model = Model(inputs=[A_IN_Cell , PX, PY, PZ], 
     outputs=[Output])

     adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=L)

     model.compile(optimizer = adam, loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
     model.summary()

     change_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=ChangeLrFactor,
                      patience=ChangeLrPatience, min_lr=0.00005)
     EarlyStop = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience = EarlyStopPatience, verbose=2, mode='min')

     Training_Data, Val_Data, Training_Label, Val_Label = train_test_split(Train_Data, Train_Label, 
     test_size=0.1)
     print('Train_Data follow=',Train_Data.shape)
     print('Training_Data follow=',Training_Data.shape)

     train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset = get_dataset()
     print('type(train_dataset)=', train_dataset)

    #beside scope
    history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=Epochs,
                    steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
                    validation_steps = valid_steps,
                    validation_data=val_dataset)
```